# What is exactly WMI and why my Linux machine fails to use it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wmi

I noticed such a line in my dmesg:

```
[    2.854164] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
```

As far as I googled, WMI is some Windows-specific tool. But my Ubuntu PC still tries to use it! I found a [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/hp-wmi.c) which is probably used in here in Linux core, but the source code doesn't tell anything to me. Even more, I can find nothing about query *0xd* here. What is this tool and how can I fix this error?

Comment: `MODULE_DESCRIPTION("HP laptop WMI hotkeys driver");` From that driver you posted. Seems like it might be something to do with media/extra function keys on your HP Laptop?

Comment: Further Google Search results: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806681

Comment: Ultimately, if you aren't noticing any actual fault, it's probably nothing to worry about. Computers throw errors *all* the time, but they don't all need to be fixed.

Comment: In particular, Linux distros frequently include every driver under the sun by default, so that they can boot and use whatever hardware you have installed without requiring user interaction. Naturally, this leads to a lot of boot-time "errors" as all these drivers attempt to access hardware which isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

So, as commentators noticed, it is not a problem at all. It doesn't cause anything to break and appears to be an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806681).